# DoctrineMongoDB : How to create classes from database?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-mongodb

It's possible to generate database from classes that have writeen by this command

```
doctrine:mongodb:schema:create
```

Is there any way to do this inversely? I mean generate classes from database?

Comment: Have you tried: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: Thank cared,but that's about mysql! Not applicable on Doctrine MongoDB.

Comment: Don't think so, as MongoDB is schemaless.

Comment: Yes,MongoDB is schemaless,but that tutorial is about generating classes from a Mysql database,Not?

Comment: You mean i can generate classes from a Mongo Database?How?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the mapping classes from your mapping metadata (YML or XML):

```
// from php app/console 
doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents      
// Generate document classes and method stubs from your mapping information.
```

Cheers!